# Can I get a regular page to redirect page in a subdirectory?

Tags: testing, optimization

I want to be able to use a clean url to test in google optimizer.... can i create a file called geolocationtest.php so that

http://neighborrow.com/geolocationtest.php

will redirect to http://neighborrow.com/v2/controllers/ and eliminate the directory problem that google doesnt like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents of geolocationtest.php:

```
<?php
header ("Location: http://neighborrow.com/v2/controllers/");
?>
```